# How to use Sessions and Templates to show/hide elements?

Tags: javascript, templates, session, meteor

I have 7 question I want to ask individually one per time on the page. I have every of them in single template and I know I should use Session.set - Session.get to show/hide them one each time. But I really don't know how and can't find an good example of how to do it. This is how I structured layout template with 7 questions inserted.

```html
<template name="layout">
{{#if first}}
 {{> submitProblem}}
{{/if}}

{{#if second}}
 {{> submitWhy}}
{{/if}}
...
</template>
```

First needs to be displayed when the page opens, and then I tried to do this with Sessions, but have no idea...

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.set("first", true);
    });

Template.layout.events({
 'click .btn1':function() {
  Session.set("first", false);
  Session.set("second", true);
 }
});
```

It seems to me that using jQuery to do show/hide with setting display:block/none is easier to do ?

Comment: Instead of having a Session value for each question individually, if you know that you only want to show one question at a time, you can have a single value that determines which question is showing.  That way you only have to change the one value instead of setting a bunch of true/false values.  Have the *first* helper look to see if Session.get('currentQuestion') == "first" and return true if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide items on page, you should define and use .hide or .hidden class in CSS. Showing/hiding items using jQuery show/hide is considered bad practice. You should render all hidden templates wrapped with .hidden class. The first template you want to show will not have hidden class.

CSS:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Templates:

```html
<template name="layout">
  {{> submitProblem}}
  {{> submitWhy}}
    ...
</template>

<template name="submitProblem">
  <div id="submit-problem">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<template name="submitWhy">
  <div id="submit-why" class="hidden">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
Template.layout.events({
  'click .btn1':function() {
    //show/hide items with removeClass()/addClass()
    $('#submit-problem').addClass('hidden');
    $('#submit-why').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use template helpers to interpret whether first, second, etc are true or false.

```
Template.layout.helpers({
    first: function() {
        return Session.get('first');
    },

    second: function() {
        return Session.get('second');
    }
});
```